# getAnnotation returns null for methods in different maven module

Tags: java, annotations, aop

I have create below annotation in maven module "A"

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface CacheDelete {...}
```

In the same module "A", I have TestPojo class, where I am using this annotation

```
@CacheDelete()
public void removeTestPojo(int id) {

}
```

I am calling this removeTestPojo() method from test case in module "A". Everything works fine here. I get the correct annotation using below code in my advice.

Advice method code CacheAspect class in module "A":

```
CacheDelete cacheDeleteAnnotation = getAnnotation((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature(),
      CacheDelete.class);
```

Get annotation method:

```
private <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(MethodSignature methodSignature,
  Class<T> annotationClass) {
     return methodSignature.getMethod().getAnnotation(annotationClass);
}
```

Problem:
Now I have a different module "B" where I am using dependency of "A" and one of the method in "B" module is annotated with @CacheDelete.

When I run the test case in module "B" for annotated method and debug the CacheAspect class, debug point comes to my advice, but my get annotation returns null here.
Any one knows what could be the reason?

Comment: Although this looks complicated, I think you should put up a [mcve]. Otherwise there isnt much we could do.

Comment: Will be bit complicated for me to do that. I myself working here to figure out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the problem it has nothing to do with different module. I annotated method that was implementation of an interface and was calling the implemented method through interface reference variable.

So when you use:

```
(MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getMethod()
```

it returns the method from interface;

Instead I replaced above code with:

```
MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
Method method = signature.getMethod();
String methodName = method.getName();
if (method.getDeclaringClass().isInterface()) {
  method = proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName,
      method.getParameterTypes());
}
```

So, this will check if method is interface, if so, I will invoke:

```
proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredMethod()
```

which gives me method of subclass.

The strange thing is, when we call subclass method through interface, call propagates to the advice(AOP) when annotation used in subclass  method but annotation doesn't propagate in subclass method.

Comment: It is nice that you solved your own problem, but next time **please** think about how to reproduce the problem first and then ask the question. I see absolutely no reason why you should not have been able to provide the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @GhostCat asked for. This is StackOverflow, not a quiz. I think I told you before.